# SharePoint Date Validation Help Needed

Tags: sharepoint, validation

I'm struggling with adding validation to a Date Column in a SharePoint list. I have looked up several sources and even trying the most basic validation of "=[Date Used]> TODAY()" as in this article: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-do-column-validation-in-sharepoint/ is not working for me.

What I want to do is to ensure that the date entered is in April but not in the future.

The formula I used is "=AND([Date Used] >= DATE(2021,3,31), [Date Used] <= TODAY())"

The edit of the column accepts this formula, but when I try to add a new record, it shows an error regardless of which date I choose, as in dates both inside and outside the desired range don't get validated as correct.

Also when I go back into the validation settings it has been changed to the following:
[image]

I'm not sure whether the changes to the formula as seen above are the cause of the issue, or if there is any other issue that I'm missing, but I would really appreciate some guidance from someone with SharePoint validation experience.

Thanks in advance

Edited: I have discovered the reason for the replacement of the column name with "#NAME?". This is an error reference. Because the display name of my column contained spaces, I was putting the display name inside the square brackets. However, sharepoint removes the spaces from the column display name so that you can more easily reference the column. Using "[DateUsed]" fixed the issue and got rid of the "#NAME?" error reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First an apology, I posted my question here before I realised there was a Sharepoint stack exchange, sorry.

It looks like one of my main issues is the fact that some of the values already present in the Sharepoint list are not conforming to the validation rule, which SharePoint does not like. I started a new list for testing purposes to see if I could make it work and I ended up with this validation formula:
=AND(testdate>=DATEVALUE("4/1/2021"),testdate<=TODAY())

This works to ensure that the value is in April and also not in the future.

SharePoint still (confusingly) changes the expression of the greater than and less than symbols to the HTML escape characters when you go back to view your validation formula like so: =AND(testdate>=DATEVALUE("4/1/2021"),testdate<=TODAY()) - so it is expected behaviour.